Elegant way with minimal redundancy for handling function parameters and starting values when plotting and fitting
The following code shows how I handle making up a function, finding starting values, fitting and plotting. You see that handling the parameter names, starting values, plotting values is highly redundant an requires changes at several locations when a new parameter is added or the order of parameters is changed.
I'm looking for an approach with no or little redundancy, so that a minimal amount of changes in the code is required when a parameter name, the order of parameters or the number of parameters is changed. I tried to tackle this problem by using the replacement list for the starting values, but as you see this is really a minor improvement.
E.g. what about doing something with DownValues to create a list of parameter names an consistently pass this list through plotting and fitting, something like that? But how?
Given this function definition
exponentiell[x_, A_, B_, k_] := (A - B)*Exp[-k*x] + B
sigmoidal2[x_, xm_, a_] := Module[{x1, x2}, x1 = xm - Log[99]/a;
  x2 = xm + Log[99]/a;
  Piecewise[{{0, x < x1}, {1, x > x2}}, 1/(1 + Exp[-a*(x - xm)])]]   
linear[x_, xm_, m_, b_] := (m*(x - xm) + b)

f[x_, A_, B_, k_, m1_, m2_, b_, xm1_, a1_, xm2_, 
  a2_] = ((1 - sigmoidal2[x, xm1, a1]) exponentiell[x, A, B, k] + 
   sigmoidal2[x, xm1, 
     a1] ((1 - sigmoidal2[x, xm2, a2])*
       linear[x, xm2, (exponentiell[xm1, A, B, k] - b)/(xm1 - xm2), 
        b] + sigmoidal2[x, xm2, a2]*linear[x, xm2, m2, b]))

I plot the function to find some reasonable values for starting values by hand
start = {A -> 164.11, B -> 127.49, 
  k -> 0.0092`, m1 -> 0.13, 
  m2 -> -0.033, b -> 109.82, 
  xm1 -> 162.69, a1 -> 53.77, 
  xm2 -> 463.53, a2 -> 0.90}
{A0, B0, k0, m10, m20, b0, xm10, a10, xm20, a20} = start[[All, 2]]

p51 = Plot[{exponentiell[x, A0, B0, 
     k0], (1 - sigmoidal[x, xm10, a10])*20 + 
     100, (1 - sigmoidal[x, xm20, a20])*20 + 100, 
    f[x, A0, B0, k0, m10, m20, b0, xm10, a10, xm20, a20]}, {x, 0, 
    550}, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}, LightGreen, LightBlue, Blue, 
     Pink}];
Show[{p4, p51}, PlotRange -> All]

Then I fit the function to a dataset (made up dataset provided for convenience):
smoothedDataDays = {{0, 164}, {10, 161}, {20, 158}, {30, 155}, {40, 
   153}, {50, 151}, {60, 149}, {70, 147}, {80, 145}, {90, 143}, {100, 
   142}, {110, 141}, {120, 140}, {130, 139}, {140, 138}, {150, 
   137}, {160, 136}, {170, 135}, {180, 134}, {190, 133}, {200, 
   132}, {210, 132}, {220, 131}, {230, 130}, {240, 129}, {250, 
   128}, {260, 127}, {270, 126}, {280, 126}, {290, 125}, {300, 
   124}, {310, 123}, {320, 122}, {330, 121}, {340, 120}, {350, 
   120}, {360, 119}, {370, 118}, {380, 117}, {390, 116}, {400, 
   115}, {410, 114}, {420, 114}, {430, 113}, {440, 112}, {450, 
   111}, {460, 110}, {470, 110}, {480, 109}, {490, 109}, {500, 
   109}, {510, 108}, {520, 108}, {530, 108}, {540, 107}, {550, 107}}
result1 = 
 FindFit[smoothedDataDays, 
  f[x, A, B, k, m1, m2, b, xm1, a1, xm2, 
   a2], {{A, A0}, {B, B0}, {k, k0}, {m1, m10}, {m2, m20}, {b, 
    b0}, {xm1, xm10}, {a1, a10}, {xm2, xm20}, {a2, a20}}, x, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]

g[x_] = f[x, A, B, k, m1, m2, b, xm1, a1, xm2, a2] /. result1

p6 = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 750}];


What are p4 and sigmoidal?  You have previously defined sigmoidal2 but not sigmoidal.

It would be nice if elegant and human efficient ways were available for all model fitting but that's just not the case for Mathematica or any other software.  Your model fit has problems (assuming my guess that sigmodal should be sigmoidal2 in your code) and those problems are hidden by using FindFit.  When developing a model NonlinearModelFit provides essential model assessment statistics.  For example, the parameter correlation matrix shows (among other things) that two of the parameters are perfectly negatively correlated with each other.

Also, m1 is one of the parameters of the function f but it appears nowhere in the definition of f.  It seems that maybe some copy-and-pasting got messed up.

@JimB yes sorry some things got messed up by simplifying for the post and copy & paste. The hint with NonlinearModelFit is interesting anyway. thx.

Maybe this will help. I use expr /. Thread[symbols -> values] and use symbols as an argument for variables or parameters. For instance:
D[expr, {symbols}] (* = Jacobian *)
FindRoot[eqns, Thread@{symbols, values}]

You have to put and keep the symbols and values in parallel order. Forgetting to do this generates bugs and should be considered a risk of this approach. If you want a tool for entering in values of variables or parameters, you could make a dialog with the following:
enterDialog // ClearAll;
enterDialog[vars_] := With[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
   CreateDialog[
    DynamicModule[{vals = ConstantArray[0, Length@vars]},
     Column@{Grid[Transpose@{
          vars,
          ConstantArray["=", Length@vars],
          Table[With[{i = i}, 
            InputField[Dynamic[vals[[i]]], Number]], {i, Length@vars}]}
        ],
       Button["Paste values", Paste[nb, vals]]}
     ]]
   ];

Clicking the button pastes the list of values, in parallel order with vars, into the notebook in which enterDialog[symbols] was executed. Most of the time, I just type values by hand, then execute Thread[symbols -> values] and make sure it's right. Checking your steps as you go is a good thing to do anyway.
An example. Both this code and the variant following it assume the user is executing statements in a notebook and is not putting the code into a package. It also assumes the user is carefully picking symbols (not expressions like x[1]) for use as variables and parameters. It would take more work to add that layer of sophistication.
params = {a, b, c};
vars = {x, y};
params0 = {0.1, 0.5, 0.4};
ClearAll[func];
func[Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] & /@ vars), 
   Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] & /@ params)] := a x^2 + b x y + c y^2;
func[Sequence @@ vars, Sequence @@ params] /. Thread[params -> params0]
% /. Thread[vars -> {1, 2}]
(*
0.1 x^2 + 0.5 x y + 0.4 y^2
2.7
*)

enterDialog[vars];   (* create an input dialog for x, y *)

enterDialog[params]; (* create one for a, b, c;
                        used to create the RHS for param0 above *)

Here is the definition of func[] that is created:
DownValues@func

(*  {HoldPattern[func[x_, y_, a_, b_, c_]] :> a x^2 + b x y + c y^2}  *)

Somewhat more involved. It assumes variables and parameters are simple symbols in the global context.
(* pollute my workspace *)
a = b = c = x = y = 0;  (* the above doesn't work if you've set values
                           for your symbols. The following code clears
                           them before *)
(* clean up my workspace *)
funcExpr = Hold[a x^2 + b x y + c y^2];
Cases[Level[funcExpr, {-1}, Hold], 
  s_Symbol /; Context@Unevaluated@s === "Global`" :> Clear[s]];

vars = {x, y};
params = DeleteCases[ (* automatic culling of parameters *)
   Union@
    Cases[Level[funcExpr, {-1}], 
     s_Symbol /; Context@Unevaluated@s === "Global`"],
   Alternatives @@ vars];
ClearAll[func];
func[Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] & /@ vars),
   Sequence @@ (Pattern[#, _]?NumericQ & /@ params)] = (* N.B,: =, not := *)
  ReleaseHold[funcExpr];

params0 = {0.1, 0.5, 0.4};
func[Sequence @@ vars, Sequence @@ params] /. Thread[params -> params0]
% /. Thread[vars -> {1, 2}]
(*
0.1 x^2 + 0.5 x y + 0.4 y^2
2.7
*)

params (* check params was done right *)

(*  {a, b, c}  *)

DownValues@func  (* check def of func *)
(*
{HoldPattern[func[x_, y_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ]] :> 
  a x^2 + b x y + c y^2}
(*

I added the ?NumericQ check just to show it's possible (and because sometimes it's important). But these few last things are probably further than you wish to go.  However, if I understand your goal right, using lists of symbols like vars and threading values and rules, Thread[{vars, vals}] and Thread[vars -> vals], resp., may relieve some of your frustration. I think it relieves some of mine.
